# recreating a scene from THE MATRIX

Tags: animation, particles, matrix

for a video project I am trying to re-create a scene from the Matrix.

[image]

https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgfycat.com%2Fru%2Fhelpfullavishboilweevil-virtualworlds-thematrix-fairuse&psig=AOvVaw10ZFkKDtxpTHuYSDItfg3i&ust=1601545854620000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCMDdya_NkOwCFQAAAAAdAAAAABBZ

This one in particular.

I am having trouble conceptualizing how to best build the spawning of the shelves. Ignore visuals, effects etc. The question is focussed only on how to spawn the shelves.

I was thinking of moving a particle effect on the x axis from left to right that spawns two particle effects that constantly push out shelves along the y axis. (to have the shelves go towards the camera and towards the horizon).

OR

Place the emitters right where they are supposed to be and trigger them with a driver that is animated.

But for the love of .... I don't really have a solid plan for this and it would be a lot of trial and error. Has someone done something like this before? Would you happen to have a good alternative idea? ;D Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe you could use the array modifier and animate the number of the duplicates?

Comment: omg, @haarigertroll lol, the simple solutions may actually once more the best. I think that may really work. I could instanciate an object with an animated array modifier to get the result .... Goog idea! Thanks man.

Comment: @haarigertroll here is my current state. (white boxed). I wonder how i could make it delayed. Maybe make an instance of one row that has the double array modifier on and somehow animate it staggered?. https://youtu.be/BIyG8j4QqIw

Comment: Also: I would probably make it much much larger and move the entire thing as well.... Kinda a nasty workaround as I would have a lot of geometry really quickly. Anyone any idea how to spawn the shelves and move them like it would be a particle?